# Anti-forgery token is not reused

Tags: asp.net-mvc, antiforgerytoken

As I read the anti-forgery system that ASP.NET MVC implements generate a token that can be reused across the same session, my question is why then this token changes every time I generate a new form in my app? I am talking about the hidden input field, not about the cookie value.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. the token is not reused.

Every page refresh will generate a new value in Form input (and Cookie as well, in case it is invalid or not exist). upon submission, the server will try to match the form value against the Cookie value.

Comment: I updated the answer. the cookie is only re-generated if invalid.

Answer (score -1):

Taken from Professional ASP.NET.MVC 3 book

> Token Verifi cation ASP.NET MVC includes a nice way of preventing CSRF
>   attacks, and it works on the principle of verifying that the user who
>   submitted the data to your site did so willingly. The simplest way to
>   do this is to embed a hidden input into each form request that
>   contains a unique value. You can do this with the HTML Helpers by
>   including this in every form:

```
<form action=”/account/register”
> method=”post”> <@Html.AntiForgeryToken()> … </form>
```

> Html.AntiForgeryToken will output an encrypted value as a hidden
>   input:  This value
>   will match another value that is stored as a session cookie in the
>   user’s browser. When the form is posted, these values will be matched
>   using an ActionFilter:

```
[ValidateAntiforgeryToken] public ActionResult
> Register(…)
```

Comment: Yes I understand the mechanism, but is it not supposed this generated token in the hidden field is reused for the next time? or maybe I understood wrong? has maybe something to do with the update from MVC3 to MVC4 I did recently?